# How to do string divided into letters then push into the next letter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace, split

```
let output ="I am a string"

const app=output.split("")

console.log(app)
```

//output
(13) [
"I",
" ",
"a",
"m",
" ",
"a",
" ",
"s",
"t",
"r",
"i",
"n",
"g"
]

then it need to change per letter into the next one in alphabetically

which means

"j","","b","n","","b,","","t","u","s","j","o","h"

after that the string must be written like ;
"jbnbtusjoh"

any opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so lets do this step by step:

```js
// first the string
let out = "I am a string"
// convert to array 
let arOut = out.split("") // gives ["I"," ", "a", "m", " ", "a"....]
// now lets get cracking : 

let mapped = arOut.map(element => element == ' ' ? element : String.fromCharCode(element.charCodeAt(0)+1))
// this get char code of element and then adds one and gets equivalent char ignores space

let newOut = mapped.join("") // we have our result

console.log(newOut)
```

Comment: thanks it is working,I want to feedback but I dont have 15 reputation thats why it doesnt feedback

Comment: @LiamEdwardRobinson : No problem, happy to help. if it helped u can accept one of the answer (the tick mark)

Answer (score 1):

After splitting, map the array of characters, convert each one to code (if not a space), add one, and convert the code back to a char:

```js
const output = 'I am a string'

const result = output.split('')
  .map(c => c === ' ' 
    ? c // ignore spaces
    : String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + 1) // convert char to code, add one, and convert back to char
  )
  .join('') // if you need a string

console.log(result)
```

You can also use `Array.from()` to directly convert the string to an array of the transformed characters:

```js
const output = 'I am a string'

const result = Array.from(
  output,
  c => c === ' ' ? c : String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + 1)
).join('')

console.log(result)
```

Comment: thank you it smootly worked,I dont have 15 reputation thats why it doesnt feedback

Answer (score -1):

Why not convert each char into ASCII and then simply increment the number?

Comment: I had no idea but Thats makes sense,

Comment: Idk, I cant feedback. Bc I don't have enough reputation